# IndentationError: unexpected indent in fcc Sea level predictor project

Tags: python, data-analysis

Please help me. New in this field and asking 1st time on this platform.

My code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import linregress

def draw_plot():
    # Read data from file
  df=pd.read_csv("epa-sea-level.csv")
    # Create scatter plot
    xpoints=df["Years"]
    ypoints=df["CSIRO Adjusted Sea Level"]
    plt.scatter(xpoints, ypoints) 

    # Create first line of best fit
  res= linregress(xpoints,ypoints)
  print(res)
  x_pred=pd.Series([i for i in range(1880,2051)])
  y_pred=res.slope*x_pred + res.intercept

  plt.plot(x_pred, y_pred,"r")
   
  # Create second line of best fit
  new_df=df.loc[df["Year"]>=2000]
  new_x=new_df["Year"]
  new_y=new_df["CSIRO Adjusted Sea Level"]
  res_2= linregress(new_x,new_y)
  x_pred2=pd.Series([i for i in range(2000,2050)])
  y_pred2=res_2.slope*x_pred2 + res_2.intercept

  plt.plot(x_pred2, y_pred2,"green")

    # Add labels and title
  plt.xlabel("Year")
  plt.ylabel("Sea Level (inches)")
  plt.title("Rise in Sea Level")
  plt.legend(fontsize="medium")
  plt.show()  
    
    # Save plot and return data for testing (DO NOT MODIFY)
    plt.savefig('sea_level_plot.png')
    return plt.gca()
```

Error:
xpoints=df["Years"]
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Link of my replit : https://replit.com/@LavishSinghal/boilerplate-sea-level-predictor-1#sea_level_predictor.py

Comment: Those are indented by 1 space. Press backspace and move them to the left

Comment: Vertically align the 3 lines below # Create scatter plot with the line that precedes that comment